# Missing dependencies in Mootools' OverText?

Tags: mootools

http://jsfiddle.net/AB5LK/2/

For the life of me, I can't get OverText working in the above example. I overrode the JSFiddle Mootools libraries (since they contain everything by default!) and inserted the ones I am using on my website, and have determined that the libraries are the ones causing the problems.

I use a slimmed-down MooTools library.

It looks as though while I selected OverText in the "More builder", there is still something missing in my libraries that causes the overtext to only become a label, and not a proper overtext.

Short of trial-and-error, does someone know which feature I am missing that will turn this overtext from a label on the right of the input box, to a proper OverText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you need to reconsider your 'slimming down':

```
this.getStyle is not a function
[Break On This Error] return(d&&d.returnPos)?c:this.setStyle...urn this.getStyle("display")!="none";
```

Removing [Element.Style](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style) is just silly, unless you're using MooTools for server side js like node and have no DOM.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar. Looks like OverText needs Element.style and Element.Dimensions, which is in core. Can't find this in the docs... Adding them to my list in the Core Builder fixed the problem. Thanks! Would've spotted this in a flash using Firebug, but was using Chrome at the time, and didn't think to check its console. Thanks for your help, Dimitar.